# Twilio integration in ionic apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, twilio, twilio-api

I have to integrate twilio in one of my hybrid application.
Can we integrate twilio voice and video calling feature in ionic apps.

Comment: You can integrate Twilio Voice and Video into Ionic apps. It may require some work integrating the Android/iOS SDKs, but it certainly can be done.

Comment: I'm thinking about integration using javascript sdk not native sdk is that possible.

Comment: It would likely be possible with Android as Chrome on Android supports WebRTC which voice and video rely on. On iOS, Apple just announced support for WebRTC in Safari 11, but that won't be out until the Autumn.